# Reference Range Calculation using Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I'm trying to calculate Reference Range Calculation using Normal Distribution for some values using the calculator in this site (https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/reference-range-lower-upper-limit.php)

When I enter in some values, I get the correct answers. But when I try to use the equation listed in the bottom of the web page :`Upper Limit = m + t₍₀.₉₇₅,ₙ₋₁₎ x √((n+1)/n) x s.d` , it gives me a wrong answer when I calculate with pen and paper.

The mean and standard deviation for the values 86,94,104,117,117 are correct (n=5, Mean = 103.6 and SD = 13.79). I'm assuming that I am calculating a wrong value for either the square root or for t-distribution t₍₀.₉₇₅,ₙ₋₁₎ which should be 2.776 for sample size (n=5) (https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/t-distribution-critical-value-table.php).

Comment: $103.6 \pm 2.776445 \times \sqrt{\frac65} \times 13.79493 \approx 145.5565$ and $61.64351$ which is close to what the calculator gives - presumably it did some premature rounding.  Is your question about the $ \sqrt{\frac65} $ term for the prediction interval?

Comment: Yes, got it. Is there any equation to calculate the Student't t distribution. I could not find one from the internet since the input values are just 0.975 and 4 (n-1).